# Changing MySQL Master in Replication: with or without MASTER_LOG?

Tags: mysql, replication

Let's say I have server A,B,C. Both B and C have Master A
A - Master
B - Slave
C - Slave

If I am going to change C's Master to Master B, can I change it immediately with query without Master Log information (edit: and also without dumping and importing the database)?

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='1.1.1.1', MASTER_USER='rep', MASTER_PASSWORD='password';
```

Or do I still need the Master Log Information ?

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='1.1.1.1', MASTER_USER='rep', MASTER_PASSWORD='password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000100', MASTER_LOG_POS=100;
```

If I need to Master Log information when switching Master, the MASTER_LOG_POS is running fast. How can I ensure that the number is not running?
If I enter the wrong MASTER LOG information, what will happen to my database?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you stop your mysql services for about 5 minutes or that can't be done?

Comment: @MauricioCacho I just trying to make it with 0 downtime.. If it is not possible. Do I need to dump the database and re-import?

Comment: And servers B and C are just slaves with read-only option? Or are there other who can write directly to the DB in those servers besides replication?

Comment: I would say B as a to-be Master should have write access, therefore it is a Master-Master for A and B (backup Master).

Comment: Do I need to dump data from B to C slave before switching Master?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that no one can write (right now, before the change) in servers B and C you could try this:

First, lock writes on Server A, so there's nothing to replicate in the Slaves.

Server A (You'll lock all tables, NOTE: You should not exit this CLI, or it'll release the lock):

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

Wait to Server B and Server C are up-to-date with the replication, check that both server are in the same Master Log File and Master Log Position!

Server B:

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

From that one you can get your new MASTER_LOG_FILE and MASTER_LOG_POS.

Server C:

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
```

So you can restart your slave from its new master. Then you can UNLOCK your tables in Server A (In the CLI that you had before):

```
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Now the only thing left is to do your CHANGE MASTER on Server C with the new MASTER_LOG_FILE and MASTER_LOG_POS that you got from Server B and everything should work fine.

**IMPORTANT:** You should check that Server B is running with log_slave_updates = TRUE and that you have log-bins too, since you'll need them for it to be a new Master.

Comment: Thanks. Means i still need the master log info right? No dumping required? How about if i mistakenly enter wrong master log info in slave ? What will happen ?

Comment: That's right, because probably the name for the binlogs are different and because the position in Server A doesn't necessarily is the same in Server B. If you enter the wrong position you could corrupt you information or stop your replication. If you start "earlier", it'll replicate again statements (duplicate information or stop replication if there's PK); if you start in positions ahead, you won't replicate some statements.

Comment: How about the running position? I got 2 slaves, 1 is running fast, 1 is almost static. Not sure why.

Comment: That could be for a lot of reasons... Different hardware, worse communication, different configuration...